# How to overload operator<< for a class member?

Tags: c++

Say I want to print a class member, I tried to overload `operator<<` for the member:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <typename K, typename V>
class MyClass {
 public:
  typedef std::map<K, V> MyMapType;
  MyMapType mymap;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(
      std::ostream& _os, const typename MyClass<K, V>::MyMapType& _map) {
    for (auto p : _map) _os << p.first << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  MyClass<std::string, int> c;
  c.mymap["a"] = 1;
  c.mymap["b"] = 2;
  std::cout << c.mymap << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But the compiler seems to ignore the definition:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'MyMapType' (aka
      'map<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>'))
  std::cout << c.mymap << std::endl;
  ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~
```

So how do I overload this correctly? Do I have to make it a class within a class, or do I need to provide an derivation of std::map?

Comment: You need to return the stream from the `operator<<` function.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Thanks for that, fixed

Comment: @immibis I know that, however I need to deal with some certian class member, not the class as a whole here, and that's what makes it little bit complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just needs to be outside the class:

```
template <typename K,typename V>
std::ostream& operator<<(
   std::ostream& _os, 
   const std::map<K,V> _map
) {
   for (auto& p : _map) _os << p.first << "\n";
   return _os;
}
```

This works because `MyMapType` is just an alias for a `std::map`, so if you are printing an instance of `MyMapType`, you are just printing a regular `std::map`.

Your original example doesn't work because you don't have an argument of type MyClass, so the function can't be found within MyClass. Friend functions can only be found outside the class if they are declared outside the class or if they have an argument of the class's type.

Comment: But what makes it different of defining it as a in-class friend function, from being outside of the class?

Comment: @chadluo: It's tricky.  friend functions can only be found if they declared outside the class or if they have an argument of the class's type.  Otherwise, the friend function is invisible outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, @Vaughn Cato, but the issue has nothing to do with the `friend` declaration. It is not necessary anyway and therefore should be avoided.

@chad luo: What should an "in-class friend function" be? That doesn't make any sense.

The compiler error message is misleading here. The function can not be found, because it does not exist. You have defined an operator with `MyClass<...>` on the left hand side and the stream and the map on the right. The compiler should complain about the nonsense declaration, before failing to find a reasonable one.

In case you define an operator as a member function, the left parameter to the operator is always `this`:

```cpp
class A { /*...*/ };
class B { /*...*/ };
class C {
    public:
        A operator << (const B& rhs);
    /*...*/
};

C c;
B b;
A a = c << b;
```

For stream operations, you will want to have the stream object on the left hand side, and `this` on the right. You could theoretically specify the operator in the stream class, but not in your user class. Since the stream class is from the standard library, that is not an option. So you simply use the external operator definition. You can call a member function inside, to avoid declaring the stream operator `friend`:

```cpp
class A {
    public:
        writeToStream(std::ostream& stream) const;
    /*...*/
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const A& a) {
    a.writeToStream(stream);
    return stream;
};
```

None of these functions has to be declared `friend`. Avoid `friend` like the plague. It is only necessary in very few really very rare cases. Don't use it, as long as you are not 100% sure, that your case is one of these.

So here is the full example corrected (untested, so beware of bugs):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <typename K, typename V>
class MyClass {
   public:
      typedef std::map<K, V> MyMapType;
      MyMapType mymap;
};

template <typename K, typename V>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,
                         const typename MyClass<K, V>::MyMapType& map) {
    for (auto p : map)
        stream << p.first << std::endl;
    return stream;
}


int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    MyClass<std::string, int> c;
    c.mymap["a"] = 1;
    c.mymap["b"] = 2;
    std::cout << c.mymap << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In your example you don't even access anything from `MyClass<...>`. There is not even a remote reason to declare it `friend`.

BTW.: `std::endl` also flushes the stream. Consider to use `"\n"` inside the operator.